# Adds ArcGIS controls in the Visual Studio Toolbox window for dragging and dropping into a design view surface

Tags: arcobjects, visual-studio

I want to drag and drop MapControl into a design view, but I have an error: System.Runtime.InteropeServices.COMException(0x80040154):Classe non enregistrée (Exception from HRESULT:80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
 I find that your map control is not registered or Class not registered,
but I don't know how to do it
in VS 2008 SDK 9.3, please help.

Answer (score 3):

Try "repairing" your ArcGIS SDK...goto **Add/Remove Programs** and try to repair the installation.

This should replace all the erroneous entries and re-register the libraries and you should be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check your com libraries. It could be they are not registered and the .net hooks into them are not able to instantiate them. This is just a guess though.

**EDIT**
 [Try this...](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=18597)
It is a link to an esri help article that describes how to register objects.
Sorry I can't help with a specific answer, I've never had issues with unregistered arc objects, but I understand the function of object registration.

**ADDITIONAL**
The only other thing I've read that might help you, is to reinstall the ArcObjects components.  Somewhere, they have been unregistered due to corruption through application crash etc.  Sorry that's all I have, I've tried to look for the DLL's associated and unregistered them to find the one that is causing issues.

Comment: thx for ur response but i'm new in arcgis can  u help me more how to do that 
thx for ur help :)

Comment: @hana hana If this leads you to an answer, could you post your solution? Cheers

Comment: of course i will post my solution, but i don't find solution yet :(

Comment: But I'm a little strapped for time at the moment!  Good luck!